# How would I hide the data and only show when there's a match?

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding

New to Knockout and just trying to show a quick data-binding example for demo purposes only. I want to keep the text in the list items hidden, and just show the matches.

http://jsfiddle.net/4y8jgsyg/

```
var viewModel = {
    query: ko.observable('')
};

viewModel.beers = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(beers, function(beer) {
        return beer.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
    });
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Do you mean to keep other items hidden when the search box is empty? Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4y8jgsyg/1/)?

Comment: Knockout 1x is really old.

Comment: @NisargShah exactly! thanks. I'm aware KO 1 is outdated. (Again this was just a quick demo, not production code.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the filter returns results only if the search term is not an empty string. This can be easily accomplished by checking for `search.length > 0`, and return an empty array if it is.

```
viewModel.beers = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
    if(search && search.length > 0) {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(beers, function(beer) {
          return beer.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
      });
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}, viewModel);
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4y8jgsyg/1/